# Consumer rate limit?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have written a producer which sends more than 12,000 messages in about 23 seconds, but my consumer seems to be getting only 6k messages per minute.

I added metrics plugin to keep an eye on the number of messages acknowledged in that queue but it's only incrementing at 6k messages per minute

```
2019-10-23 11:09:46,815 INFO  [io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry] artemis.messages.acknowledged{address=my.controller.queue,broker=0.0.0.0,queue=my.controller.queue} value=40156
2019-10-23 11:10:46,818 INFO  [io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry] artemis.messages.acknowledged{address=my.controller.queue,broker=0.0.0.0,queue=my.controller.queue} value=46157
```

message.count for above logs is as follows

```
2019-10-23 11:09:46,818 INFO  [io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry] artemis.unrouted.message.count{address=my.controller.queue,broker=0.0.0.0} value=2
2019-10-23 11:10:46,815 INFO  [io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry] artemis.delivering.durable.message.count{address=my.controller.queue,broker=0.0.0.0,queue=my.controller.queue} value=0
```

I have following connection URL parameters:

```
?minLargeMessageSize=10485760;compressLargeMessages=true;producerWindowSize=-1;reconnectAttempts=-1;confirmationWindowSize=1048576&consumerWindowSize=-1&throttleRate=-1&consumerMaxRate=-1
```

Comment: @justin-bertram any inputs?

Comment: What does the `message-count` of the queue show after you've sent the 12,000 messages? Are you sending persistent or non-persistent messages? What is the consumer doing when it receives the message? Do all the 12,000 messages get consumed eventually?

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with message-count. these are non-persistent messages. Problem processes those messages. I have noted that my application is able to process those messages as they arrive asynchronously. messages do get consumed eventually.

Comment: mostly message.count is zero. I have seen the surge occasionally. for example the following log ```2019-10-23 10:55:14,857 INFO  [io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry] artemis.routed.message.count{address=my.controller.queue,broker=0.0.0.0} value=121725```  ```2019-10-23 10:56:14,857 INFO  [io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry] artemis.routed.message.count{address=my.controller.queue,broker=0.0.0.0} value=127725```

Comment: my question is why consumer rate is at 6k/minute is it some kind of queue configuration?. I set up a cluster of about 7 brokers and I m getting 29k/minute incoming messages whereas we had openmq where message incoming rate was  39k/minute messages

Comment: For what it's worth, the message-count metrics you posted in your question do not reflect the total number of messages in the queue that I was requesting. The `artemis.unrouted.message.count` applies only to an address (i.e. not a queue) and reflects the number of messages sent to the address that *were not* routed to a queue. The `artemis.delivering.durable.message.count` is the number of *durable* (i.e. persistent) messages which are being delivered. Since you're sending non-durable (i.e. non-persistent) messages this value will always be 0.

Comment: Since the messages get consumed eventually you can safely assume none were lost.

Comment: yes I was not worried about them being lost. I was more worried about performance.  with openmq we were able to receive messages at about 30-40k but with Artemis we were restricted to 6k. Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm curious. Now that you fixed your framework code what consumption numbers are you seeing?

Comment: @JustinBertram now numbers are skyrocketing. the consumer is getting 40k-50k messages per minute. but my producing messages at 40-50k per minute rate as well. I m using CORE protocol. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the throttling reason. In our framework code, we were setting

`com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimite outboundRateLimiter` to `100`

so only `100*60=6000` per minute, messaging going out every minute.